# Find the rank of an element in an array without sorting

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Given an array of n element and an element x in the array, is there a fast way to find the rank of x, without sorting it?

As I'm now dealing with a very large array, an algorithm with O(n) time complexity would still be too slow for me to work with which is why I am trying to find other alternative other than sorting.

EDIT:

So right now my algorithm is something like:

```py
for x in list:
    A = x.dot(B) ## return a numpy array
    rank = findRank(a, A) ## find the rank of a in A
    doSomething2(rank)
```

So here my bottleneck is findRank(), in my current implementation, I first sort the array and then find the rank of the element in the sorted array.

Comment: This is what db are for. Using sql orderby for example. if your array is so large that sorting is that slow then put it into a db. What technology are you using?

Comment: You'll need an O(n) algorithm: if you would omit looking at one element, that value could change the order that x has. So you need at the least inspect every value. Unless of course you prepare the array with sorting, or some other data structure.

Comment: Do you need multiple queries for different x with the same array? Please give  more problem details

Comment: @Steve Tomlin just python. But since the array will be discarded and replaced with a new array immediately and repeat the findRank() operation, would the overhead incurred in creating a database for it be justified?

Comment: If you create the array each time, you already spend O(n) time on the creation, so I don't see why you would not look up the rank at the same time, or do it in a O(n) process also.

Comment: In the edit you describe an algorithm that is O(nlogn), but you should do it in O(n) by a simple scan & count.

Comment: If there is no additional assumption (or additional index structure) on the data, it is impossible to attain a sublinear asymptotic runtime complexity; otherwise, the rank would not depend on the entire input.

Comment: Not really much you can do, could be an XY program where knowing more about "dosomething" and "dosomething2" and what you are trying to achieve with those would lead to insight to solve this. There are O(N) ways to do this, and there are sublinear ways to approximate the rank, but exact rank must be linear unless you can build the array in such a way that it is at least semi-sorted.

Comment: `rank = np.sum(A < a)`

Answer (score 1):

Without assuming extra preparations (creating a tree data structure, or sorting), which in itself would require at least *O(n)* time, there is no way you can hope to determine the rank of a value in an unsorted array in sub linear time: every value in that array potentially plays a role in determining that rank, so you need to inspect all array values.

As the algorithm *already* has a linear time complexity for the execution of:

```
A = x.dot(B) ## return a numpy array
```

...this should not be an issue.

You mention in comments that your implementation of `findRank` sorts A. This is sub optimal, as it represents a *O(nlogn)* time complexity.

Instead, just count the number of values in the array that are smaller than the value you need the rank of. That will correspond to the zero-based rank:

```
rank = np.sum(A < a)
```

Comment: Your answer begins with "there is no way you can hope to determine the rank of a value in an unsorted array"; then you proceed to explain how to determine the rank of a value in an unsorted away.

Comment: Thanks for noting that, @Stef. I intended to say "...in sub linear time". Edited.